# Executing Restkit addFetchRequestBlock in Swift for orphan deletion

Tags: ios, swift, restkit

(UPDATE: Updated code to implement some of Wain's suggestions below.)

I have been fighting and fighting with the following: I have an app - in Swift - that connects to an API with Restkit to pull down events as they are added/updated. The following is an example of some of the implementation.

API JSON:

```
[
    {
        id: 7,
        title: "Event 1",
        description: "Lorem ipsum dolor...",
    },
    {
        id: 8,
        title: "Event 2",
        description: "Lorem ipsum dolor...",
    }
]
```

AppDelegate:

```
// Setting up object manager
let baseURL = NSURL(string: "http://url.com")
var objectManager = RKObjectManager(baseURL: baseURL)
objectManager.managedObjectStore = managedObjectStore

// Initialize managed object model and store
var managedObjectModel = NSManagedObjectModel.mergedModelFromBundles(nil)
managedObjectStore = RKManagedObjectStore(managedObjectModel: managedObjectModel)
objectManager.managedObjectStore = managedObjectStore

// Complete CoreData stack initialization
managedObjectStore.createPersistentStoreCoordinator()
let storePath = RKApplicationDataDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent("MyApp.sqlite")
let seedPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("RKSeedDatabase", ofType: "sqlite")
var error:NSError?
var persistantStore = managedObjectStore.addSQLitePersistentStoreAtPath(storePath, fromSeedDatabaseAtPath: seedPath, withConfiguration: nil, options: nil, error: nil)

// Creating the managed object contexts
managedObjectStore.createManagedObjectContexts()

// Configure a managed object cache to ensure we don't create duplicate objects
managedObjectStore.managedObjectCache = RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache(managedObjectContext: managedObjectStore.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext)


// Mapping events to Restkit
var eventsMapping = RKEntityMapping(forEntityForName: "Event", inManagedObjectStore: managedObjectStore)
eventsMapping.identificationAttributes = ["eventID", "name", "eventDescription"]
    eventsMapping.addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary([
           "id":"eventID",
           "title":"name",
           "description":"eventDescription"
    ])

// Response descriptor for Events
let eventsDescriptor = RKResponseDescriptor(mapping: eventsMapping, method: RKRequestMethod.GET, pathPattern: "/api/v1/events", keyPath: nil, statusCodes: NSIndexSet(index:200))

// Registering mappings with object manager
objectManager.addResponseDescriptorsFromArray([eventsDescriptor])
```

An update method in a database model:

```
class func runUpdates(completion:(updated:Bool) -> Void) {
   RKObjectManager.sharedManager().getObjectsAtPath("/api/v1/events", parameters: nil,
       success:{ operation, mappingResult in               
          completion(updated:true)
       },
       failure:{ operation, error in
          completion(updated:false)
       }
   )
}
```

So far, this actually works pretty good: Restkit pulls the events from the API and saves them into Core Data, it's good about updating changed events, etc. The only thing is does NOT do is delete orphaned events, so if an event is deleted on the server it remains on my local data. No good.

So after Googling and Googling and reading other SO threads, the first thought was that apparently Restkit won't delete orphans if it is a POST request. Only I'm definitely making a GET request here as seen in the eventDescriptor.

The second thing I came across is that apparently orphans will only be deleted with an addFetchRequestBlock, so apparently I shouldn't use getObjectsAtPath. Examples of this in Swift is very sparse and lacking, but based on the Objective C examples I came up with this to replace the getObjectsAtPath.

```
RKObjectManager.sharedManager().addFetchRequestBlock { (url:NSURL!) -> NSFetchRequest! in
   var pathMatcher = RKPathMatcher(pattern: "/api/v1/events")
   var match = pathMatcher.matchesPath(url.relativePath, tokenizeQueryStrings: false, parsedArguments: nil)
   if(match) {
      var fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Event")
      return fetchRequest
   } else {
      return nil
   }
}
```

However, it doesn't work at all: it automatically returns nil (and even ignores any break threads around the pathMatcher prior to checking the pathMatcher to try and see what it's doing).

Clearly, I'm overlooking something or not writing the method in the correct way / doing something wrong, any ideas on what's up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are a little confused about the purpose of the fetch request block. It is there to finds objects which can be deleted, but it has nothing to do with downloading. So, you configure the block when you configure your mapping, and then it swings into action after your GET is complete to tidy up old (orphan) items.

As an aside you should really be using `identificationAttributes` on your mapping and creating a `RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache` to use as the store `managedObjectCache`. This allows proper matching of existing items when new content is received.

Comment: Thank you for this. Aside from above suggestions, I needed to update some of my Core Data stack stuff for Restkit (it was still using some default boilerplate).

I placed the fetch request block after the mapping in AppDelegate and it indeed did get called whenever the getObjects method ran. From there, it was able to successfully delete an event I deleted from the server.

Only issue now is I'm getting an assertion failure on the table (NSFetchedResultsController), but out of scope of the original question and I still have some stuff to update first based on above changes. Thanks again.

Comment: Just a brief mention to anyone who might have a similar issue: the assertion failure I mentioned in my above response comment was simply due to an issue I had in my NSFetchedResultsController methods, nothing to do with RestKit. So if you have a similar issue, check your didChangeObject / didChangeSection methods and make sure the respective Insert / Delete / etc cases are correctly defined.